# htaccess - insert additional path

Tags: .htaccess

I need to insert an additional path to an URL an forward it by 301. An example:

Old URL: http://example.com/products/cf1/

NEW URL: http://example.com/products/additional-path/cf1/

I tried the this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?products/[^additional-path]*(.*)$ /products/additional-path/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the new url exist?

Comment: Yes - sure. But the 301 forward ends in a loop.

Comment: Do you want to redirect **old url** to **new** or new to old?

Comment: old to new. The old one does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect **/product/foobar** to **/product/path/foobar** , you can use the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/]+)/?$ /product/path/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser cache or try a diffrent browser to test this.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you very much!